# Why is VNC server greatly sluggish when it is not plugged into a monitor?

Tags: x11vnc

### Introduction

I have a small Intel "NUC" computer running Mint LTS 21.1. The computer has 4GB of RAM, and runs an internal mSATA drive. On boot it starts up the desktop immediately i.e. there is no explicit login step. I have set up x11vnc so that the current desktop session is shared. I plan to access it from another Linux machine over a domestic LAN.

### Problem

If the NUC is plugged into a monitor then several observations can be made:

- The desktop video mode on the NUC can do 4K, but scales down to whatever the monitor can do. I have monitors that set the desktop to either 2560x1400 or 1920x1280.
- The shared VNC screen takes on the same dimensions as the monitor

This is fine. However if the NUC is not plugged into a monitor then different observations can be made:

- The desktop video size is much smaller, despite being hardwired into the VNC Server launch command
- The redraw speed is extremely sluggish - a few seconds per whole screen refresh - and it is only just about usable

Here is the VNC server launch command on the NUC:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# We force a decent screen size, since in headless mode
# the desktop just uses a (very small) default.
#
# I previously used TLS, but Remmina shows a TLS error,
# and Remmina seems to be miles better than the stock
# Mint VNC client. If it is needed again:
#
#    -ssl /home/music/.vnc/certs/server.pem \

x11vnc \
    -rfbauth /home/music/.vnc/passwords \
    -o /home/music/.vnc/server.log \
    -nossl \
    -geometry 1920x1200 \
    -forever \
    -bg
```

This script is run by Startup Applications so that VNC Server is always started on boot.

### Notes

I originally used the stock "SSH/SSH VNC Viewer" on the client side; however the UI is so rudimentary as to be unusable, especially in regards to screen scaling. However at least this supported TLS connections. I then swapped to Remmina on the client, and while this has a much slicker user experience, TLS failed, so I had to turn it off completely. However, this is all on a trusted LAN, so the loss of TLS is not a major bother (and I did not want to spend much time on this side issue).

### Question

The desktop session is still created even when a monitor is not attached. I suspect that this is why `-geometry` does not do anything - the default session size is much smaller, and one cannot share a screen larger than the session screen size.

Moreover, with a monitor I get a VNC refresh speed of around 8fps, but without a monitor it drops to around 0.25fps, which is rather difficult to use. I suspect that onboard video acceleration is applied in the first case and not the second, though that is a guess.

How can I get VNC performance to be the same for both, with a screen size that is the same for both? Should I persist with x11vnc, or is there a VNC server package that is better?

Comment: I've just found [this over on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/679135/how-do-i-set-new-screen-resolution-for-a-headless-server-using-teamviewer-10) - this shows how to add a video mode with larger dimensions. I will try this tomorrow. I don't imagine this will tackle the lag problem, but will report back. Answers are welcome in the meantime.

Comment: I have self-flagged my question as a [duplicate of this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/636441/trick-linux-mint-cinnamon-in-headless-mode-to-think-a-monitor-is-connected) (I don't mind if it is put on hold or left open). I fear that the answers on the other post are not very satisfying, but the link to the GitHub page looks like there are a number of things to try.